# Can't access C macro in a linked file

Tags: c

I have distilled my question to the following three files. I am trying to capture the name of the function that calls a() through a wrapper function a_wrapper() that is called through a macro in a different file than my main. My issue is that the a_wrapper function doesn't seem to get called when calling a() from main.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef a_h
#define a_h


extern void a();
extern void a_wrapper(char* funcName);

#endif /* a_h */
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void a()
{
    printf("I'm in a\n");
}

void a_wrapper(char* funcName)
{
    a();
    printf("I'm in a_wrapper\n");
}

#define a() a_wrapper(__func__)
```

Comment: You define the macro at the end of a non-header file, so nothing will ever see it.

Comment: Macros are expanded by the pre-processor.  main.c never sees the macro, so it's never expanded.  You'll have to put it in your header.

Comment: @Siguza When placing it at the top of the file or in the header file, I get an error on a_wrapper in Xcode saying: Redefinition of 'a_wrapper'

Comment: You have `#define a()...` at the end of `a.c` where is not visible to `main`. And `main` includes `a.h` which declares `a()` as extern.

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for that, realized I didn't need the extern

Comment: What you're asking for here won't work, as any definition of `a()` ends up impacting the implementation of `a_wrapper()` too, so it ends up calling itself. What is the goal here? If it's to rewrap that function, why not just export the wrapper version as `a()` and have an `a_orig()` which you call within it?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this to put the macro in the header, and then call/define the *real* function with redundant parentheses to avoid the macro:

a.h

```
#ifndef a_h
#define a_h

#define a() a_wrapper(__func__)
extern void a_wrapper(char* funcName);

#endif /* a_h */
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void (a)()
{
    printf("I'm in a\n");
}

void a_wrapper(char* funcName)
{
    (a)();
    printf("I'm in a_wrapper\n");
}
```

Comment: Or just put `#undef a` after `#include "a.h"` in `a.c`.

Answer (score 0):

### Make the macro visible to source files

Preprocessor macros are visible only within a translation unit (the source file being compiled along with all files it includes). They do not apply when linking different object modules. So you must put the definition of the macro in `a.h`; `a.h` must contain:

```
#define a() a_wrapper(__func__)
```

Of course, this must go after any other use of `a` in `a.h`, or it will replace that `a` with `a_wrapper(__func__)`, which is undesired.

Another reason the macro must be in `a.h` is that `__func__` is only works when it is inside the source code of a function, per C 2018 6.4.2.2 1. It is not a run-time operation that can look up the name of a function. It is an identifier that is resolved when each function is compiled.

### Prevent the macro from breaking a.c

Once you define the macro in `a.h`, uses of `a` in `a.c` will break because they are replaced by `a_wrapper(__func__)`. Two ways to prevent this are:

- In `a.c`, after `#include "a.h"`, put `#undef a`. That removes the definition of the macro for the rest of `a.c`.
- Wherever `a` is used in `a.c`, replace it with `(a)`. Function-like macros are replaced only when they appear with a `(` immediately after them, as in `a()`. Changing this to `(a)()` separates the `a` from the `(`, preventing this replacement. However, the `(a)` still serves to declare, define, and call the function, as the C grammar allows parentheses in these uses.